# For writing up the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, what is the order of $|f(x)-L|$ and $|x-a|$ at the end?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

To elaborate, do you...

1. $0<|x-a|<\delta$ and then add to that so that you build up to $|f(x)-L|$ and then show that this is less than $\epsilon$ by using the $\epsilon-\delta$ relationship you found earlier.
2. $|f(x)-L|$ and then break it down so you can substitute $|x-a|<\delta$ and then show that the former is less than $\epsilon$ by using the $\epsilon-\delta$ relationship you found earlier.

In the way the final part of the definition is written ("if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$"), does it matter which choice you use, or it just preference? I've seen books do both ways, but from what I've seen, the second option is more common.

In terms of "If P, then Q" which would you want to work with first - P, or Q?

Comment: When you have a specific function given, then it is always easier to break that function and to get the form and substitute $|x-a|<\delta$, because it is not easier to start for $|x-a|<\delta$ and build the function. I think unless **it is some part of a proof**, mostly we use the second way to solve a given question. (offcourse both are equivalent, so it depends on which is more easy to proceed with.)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't matter how you prove the final statement.

But the only important thing that you should consider is:

In fact, $\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon$. and $\epsilon$ can be any positive number.